# Creating Link From LEFT Function

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a dynamic link in Excel 2010. Below I have created a function that gives me the parent folder workbook to reference. When I try and add ' to the LEFT keyword excel does not accept it. What I'm trying to do is reference workbook in parent folder and want to make sure when the parent folder is moved all files stay linked.

My question is how to create a Link from the LEFT function below. Thanks

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename"),LARGE((MID(CELL("filename"),ROW(1:255),1)="\")*IFERROR(SEARCH("\",CELL("filename"),ROW(1:255)),0),2)) & CONCATENATE("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1")
```

Comment: You mean `="'"&LEFT...` does not work? Also I think you can remove the concatenate.

Comment: Good one, but it adds the apostrophe but does not link to the file.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming your left formula is correct (not tested):

```
=INDIRECT("'["& LEFT(CELL("filename"),LARGE((MID(CELL("filename"),ROW(1:255),1)="\")*IFERROR(SEARCH(" \",CELL("filename"),ROW(1:255)),0),2))&"Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1")
```

Comment: Getting Closer, The Formula is correct i think since im using regular link to the same workbook and seeing against that. Right now im getting Invalid Cell reference error.

Comment: I think I was missing a comma. Better now? If not remove the indirect to check that the string is as expected and correct as required.

Comment: excel still doesn't like it, gives me Invalid Cell reference.

Comment: My last try for today, moving the [

Comment: Still got problems with it. Ill take your answer since its what i tried to do but excel keeps bugging for some reason.

Comment: =INDIRECT('C:\Users\ppetrenko\Desktop\TEST\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1) also fails if I hardcode without the LEFT function

Comment: and `=INDIRECT('[C:\Users\ppetrenko\Desktop\TEST\Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1)`?

Comment: last last: `=INDIRECT("'[C:\Users\ppetrenko\Desktop\TES T\Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1")`?

Comment: You are right brettdj, INDIRECT doesn't work with closed workbook. Are there any commands that can be used to create a link to closed workbook?

Answer (score 0):

To create a link to a file you need to enter the full path and reference directly into a formula (INDIRECT won't work). One way to put a link to the parent folder in the active cell is with this VBA command:

```
activecell = "='" & activeworkbook.path & "\..\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1"
```

Paths are stored relative to the workbook as stated in the response to your previous linked question. It's also possible to retrieve values from closed workbooks using a udf such as:

```
Function Eval(Text As String)
Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
eval = xl.ExecuteExcel4Macro(Application.ConvertFormula(Text, xlA1, xlR1C1, True))
Set xl = Nothing
End Function
```

or by downloading Laurent Longre's Morefunc.xll free add-in which has a function INDIRECT.EXT, (beware however that these methods are less efficient and links aren't created so won't update when folders are moved).